# Improving O(n) while looping through a 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

A goal of mine is to reduce my O(n^2) algorithms into O(n), as it's a common algorithm in my Array2D class. Array2D holds a multidimensional array of type T. A common issue I see is using doubly-nested for loops to traverse through an array, which is slow depending on the size.

As you can see, I reduced my doubly-nested for loops into a single for loop here. It's running fine when I execute it. Speed has surely improved. Is there any other way to improve the speed of this member function? I'm hoping to use this algorithm as a model for my other member functions that have similar operations on multidimensional arrays.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Fills all items within the array with a value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ob">The object to insert.</param>
        void fill(const T &ob)
        {
            if (m_array == NULL)
                return;

            //for (int y = 0; y < m_height; y++)
            //{
            //  for (int x = 0; x < m_width; x++)
            //  {
            //      get(x, y) = ob;
            //  }
            //}

            int size = m_width * m_height;
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                get(x, y) = ob;

                x++;

                if (x >= m_width)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - if indeed the goal is to fill a 2D array, then you can't do better than O(N^2) (assuming an NxN array).

Comment: Has it improved? I see even more work being performed.

Comment: There is no difference in the efficiency of your first version (in comments) and the second version.

Comment: Maybe it's been a while, but I learned before that one for loop is an O(n). Two for's is O(n^2). That suggests to me that one for loop is more efficient.

Comment: Previously you had `m_height` `y < m_height` tests and `y++`s and `m_height * m_width` `x < m_width` tests and `x++`s. Now you have `m_height` `y++`s and `m_height * m_width` `i < size`s, `i++`s, `x++`s, and `x >= m_width`s. You time complexity looks lower, but you're doing more actual work.

Comment: @Phil, but n^2==n in this case. You've just rearranged your array, you haven't changed its size.

Comment: In your case the one loop is n^2 as long as the two loops so *zero sum gain*.

Comment: @Phil The question is how many times is get(x,y) being called in each of your versions?

Comment: @user4581301, so, my time complexity is lower, but with the additional if statement, I'm assuming this is what you mean by more work, which makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like the first algorithm was better off. The book said there are optimizations, which he didn't care to include, so it got me thinking anyway. Back to computer science courses.

Comment: how do you store your array

Comment: The complexity actually hasn't changed: the nested loops accessed each element once, the unrolled loop accesses each element once. Both are linear in the number of elements. Just because you have two loop doesn't mean operations are O(n*n) and having one loop doing the same work brings it down to O(n).

Comment: I didn't think about width*height and the extra time it takes to process. That says it all about not being O(n).

Comment: Look at the answer below to see my timing in milliseconds for both algorithms, and how the first algorithm is slightly faster.

Comment: There is a cool talk from CppCon 2016 about optimization, cache and 2D Array traversals right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP6NxVxDQIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure things are contiguous in memory as cache behavior is likely to dominate the run-time of any code which performs only simple operations.

For instance, don't use this:

```
int* a[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  a[i] = new int[10];
//Also not this
std::vector< std::vector<int> > a(std::vector<int>(10),10);
```

Use this:

```
int a[100];
//or
std::vector<int> a(100);
```

Now, if you need 2D access use:

```
for(int y=0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
for(int x=0;x<WIDTH;x++)
  a[y*WIDTH+x];
```

Use 1D accesses for tight loops, whole-array operations which don't rely on knowledge of neighbours, or for situations where you need to store indices:

```
for(int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH;i++)
  a[i];
```

Note that in the above two loops the number of items touched is `HEIGHT*WIDTH` in both cases. Though it may *appear* that one has a time complexity of `O(N^2)` and the other `O(n)`, it should be obvious that the net amount of work done is `HEIGHT*WIDTH` in both cases. It is better to think of `N` as the total number of items touched by an operation, rather than a property of the way in which they are touched.

Comment: You're right about WIDTH*HEIGHT. The time to complete is the same then, and the first algorithm seems more efficient with less work.

Comment: @Phil: The flat array addressing can certainly confer benefits in some situations. The best way to know which is faster in your particular use-case is through profiling.

Comment: I used a timer in milliseconds to test filling a map of (2000,2000). The original algorithm (first one) had 142 milliseconds. The second algorithm had 172 milliseconds. With (8000,8000), I had 2344 milliseconds with the first algorithm, and 2375 milliseconds with the second. Both suggest the first algorithm is slightly faster. That's a good way of testing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also found that the 1D access for this operation is slightly faster as well. It had 92 milliseconds instead of 142 milliseconds--nice. I don't know why I didn't think of that one, as I use it elsewhere. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I was doing another operation between timer::start() and timer::stop(), but after removing that, it still shows the milliseconds are much lesser using 1D access.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can compute Big O by counting loops, but not always.

```
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Big O is a measure of "How many times is `doStuff` executed?" With the nested loops above it is executed MxN times.

If we flatten it to 1 dimension

```
for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i++)
{
    doStuff();
}
```

We now have one loop that executes MxN times. One loop. No improvement.

If we unroll the loop or play games with something like [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

```
for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i += N)
{
     doStuff(); // 0
     doStuff(); // 1
     .... 
     doStuff(); // N-1
}
```

We still have MxN calls to `doStuff`. Some days you just can't win with Big O. If you must call `doStuff` on every element in an array, no matter how many dimensions, you cannot reduce Big O. But if you can find a smarter algorithm that allows you to avoid calls to `doStuff`... That's what you are looking for.

For Big O, anyway. Sometimes you'll find stuff that has an as-bad-or-worse Big O yet it outperforms. One of the [classic examples of this is `std::vector` vs `std::list`.](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists) Due to caching and prediction in a modern CPU, `std::vector` scores a victory that slavish obedience to Big O would miss.

Side note (Because I regularly smurf this up myself) O(n) means if you double n, you double the work. This is why O(n) is the same as O(1,000,000 n). O(n<sup>2</sup>) means if you double n you do 2<sup>2</sup> times the work. If you are ever puzzled by an algorithm, drop a counter into the operation you're concerned with and do a batch of test runs with various Ns. Then check the relationship between the counters at those Ns.