# What is the Complexity of Find() Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have two versions of find function, both of which search an integer value in an array and return its position if exists. Function `find1()` will search up to **N** elements in worst case on the other hand `find2()` function will search up to **N/2** elements in worst case. Does it mean `find2()` functions complexity is reduced into **O(N/2)**?

I assume the array `arr` contains non-duplicating values.

**Function: find1()**

```
int find1(int value){
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if (arr[i] == value){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Function: find2()**

```
int find2(int value){
    for (int i = 0, j = N - 1; i <= j; i++, j--){
        if (arr[i] == value){
            return i;
        }
        if (arr[j] == value){
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Both version appear to search the same number of elements. The second version simply searches two elements each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes, but the loop will run half. does it reduce the overall complexity? or still it will be considered a O(N) function? I just want to be clear about how it works. Thanks @Galik

Comment: They're both O(n). `n/2` is the same as `n` in complexity analysis. In this case it's doubly so since each operation in the `n/2` case is twice as complex as the operations in the `n` case.

Comment: No. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis

Comment: The secon loop runs half as many times but does twice as many tests. So one half multiplied by two = 1. The two are exactly the same.

Comment: If you have to visit every element there is no way to reduce Big O. [Here's an example of a 2D array where various attempts at removing the inner loop are attempted and all have the same result.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378975/4581301)

Comment: Read any competent book on algorithms and you'll get the precise definition of complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, the first version does in the worst case *n* iterations, and, in each iteration, does a constant number of operations. The second version does in the worst case *n / 2* iterations, and, in each iteration, also does a constant number of operations, but a larger constant. Thus, there is no reason to think that the first is *O(n)* and the second is *O(n / 2)*.

In any case, *O(n) = O(n / 2)*. By the [definition of *O*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), *O(n)* means that there is a constant *c<sub>1</sub>* such that for every *n > n<sub>1</sub>*,

*f(n) < c<sub>1</sub> n*.

Similarly, *O(n / 2)* means that there is a constant *c<sub>2</sub>* such that for every *n > n<sub>2</sub>*,

*f(n) < c<sub>2</sub> n / 2 = (c<sub>2</sub> / 2) n*.

Since for any *n > max(n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>)* the inequality holds for *c<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>2</sub> / 2*, each of these two implies the other one.

Comment: Thanks Tavory. Its clear now.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan You're welcome. All the best.